# Form submission in new window using Javascript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I've an internet firewall login and to prevent login timeout and  keep logged in I want to send POST login request using JavaScript in a new Window  every 30 seconds or so.

The following function is working in Chrome but not in Firefox. What could be the reason?

```
function callback(data) //this keeps getting called every 30 secs from Ajax response
{
    if (data && data.login && data.passwd)
    {

        w = w || window.open('', 'formresult', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=100,width=100,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=yes');

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", 'http://firewall:8090/login.xml');

        form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "password");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", data.passwd); 
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "username");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", data.login);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);

        w.document.body.appendChild(form);

        form.submit();

    }
}
```

if I change

```
w.document.body.appendChild(form);
```

to

```
document.body.appendChild(form);
```

then Firefox is appending the form in the main window and not in the opened one.

**EDIT: I see "Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'" in the Firefox console**

Comment: Which firefox version? it was a bug earlier

Comment: I've checked this on 26 & 29.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the question "Form submission in new window using Javascript not working in Firefox" still has relevance. In order for the form submit to work properly and open in a new window, you need to do the following:

1. attach the form to the DOM (document.body)
2. set the target attribute on the form to '_blank'

   ```
   var form = document.createElement('form');
   var input = document.createElement('input');

   form.target = '_blank';
   form.action = data.websiteUrl;
   form.method = 'post';

   input.name = 'username';
   input.value = 'myUserName';

   document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.appendChild(input);
   form.submit();
   ```

As to pinging the server every 30 seconds.. there has to be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do instead of doing a form post.

Comment: Just for clarity the above code doesn't attach the form to the dom.